# Use openjson to get columns from JSON with multiple arrays of elements

Tags: sql-server, open-json

JSON input looks like this:

```
{
"reporting.unit": [ "F-1", "F-2", "F-3"],
"notional.lc": [  100.1, 140.2, 150.3]
}
```

Desired Output:

| reporting.unit | notional.lc |
| --- | --- |
| F-1 | 100.1 |
| F-2 | 140.2 |
| F-3 | 150.3 |

Note I have upwards of 20 columns and many more elements

I tried:

```
    DECLARE @json nvarchar(max);
    SELECT @json = '{
    "reporting.unit": [ "F-1", "F-2", "F-3"],
    "notional.lc": [  100.1, 140.2, 150.3]
    }';
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON (@json);
```

but the result was:

| key | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| reporting.unit | [ "F-1", "F-2", "F-3"] | 4 |
| notional.lc | [ 100.1, 140.2, 150.3] | 4 |

Comment: Will each key have the same number of values in their arrays?

Comment: @griv yes it will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OPENJSON` with multiple `JOIN`'s to join your columns together using your array keys to get the values in a column/row format.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max);
SELECT @json = '{
"reporting.unit": [ "F-1", "F-2", "F-3"],
"notional.lc": [  100.1, 140.2, 150.3]
}';
SELECT 
  a.value AS [reporting.unit],
  b.value AS [notional.lc]
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$."reporting.unit"') a
JOIN OPENJSON(@json, '$."notional.lc"') b 
ON a.[key] = b.[key]
```

**Result:**

| reporting.unit | notional.lc |
| --- | --- |
| F-1 | 100.1 |
| F-2 | 140.2 |
| F-3 | 150.3 |

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/AgN9ac46).**

Answer (score 1):

Already +1 on griv's answer ... it was my first thought as well.

However, and just for fun, I wanted to try an alternative **which ODDLY enough had a lower batch cost 40% vs 60% (image below)**

I should also note that 2016 requires a literal while 2017+ can be an expression

**Example**

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max);
SELECT @json = '{
"reporting.unit": [ "F-1", "F-2", "F-3"],
"notional.lc": [  100.1, 140.2, 150.3]
}';

Select ReportingUnit = JSON_VALUE(@json,concat('$."reporting.unit"[',N,']'))
      ,NotionalLC    = JSON_VALUE(@json,concat('$."notional.lc"[',N,']'))
 From ( Select Top 25 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
          From master..spt_values n1
      ) A
 Where JSON_VALUE(@json,concat('$."reporting.unit"[',N,']')) is not null
```

**Results**

```
ReportingUnit   NotionalLC
F-1             100.1
F-2             140.2
F-3             150.3
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Interesting answer. What tool are you using to visualize/calculate the batch?

Comment: @griv In SS Management Studio, just click on the toolbar button [Display Estimated Execution Plan] or Cntrl+L

Comment: I forgot about this feature. Thanks! @John